# What do these numbers mean on the network tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-performance

In the network tab, under the list of all the HTTP requests, I see a summary. For example:
[image: network summary]

- 213 requests
- 2.5 MB transferred
- 7.2 MB resources
- Finish: 2.1 Min
- DOMContentLoaded: 1.23 s
- Load: 3.17 s

Chrome's documentation has an [extensive article about this tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/), but it doesn't describe these summary data.

Some of these are self-explanatory. 213 Total HTTP requests have been sent, and it took 1.23 seconds from the first request until the `document.DOMContentLoaded` event was fired. The big value for finished value actually makes sense because this page has a repeating 'ping' event for click tracking. However, the other values are a bit confusing.

Why are there two very different numbers for transferred and resources — i.e. what the difference between a transferred byte and a resource byte? Also, what does the "Load" time represent exactly — is that the time until `window.load` event or something else?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DevTools documentation points to [MDN's `load` event page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) to describe the "Load" number. So yes, "Load" is the time from navigation until window.load.

"Transferred" refers to bytes across the wire. "Resources" refers to the weight of those files once they're downloaded and un-compressed, as shown in the [DevTools reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#total-size).

Downloading [jQuery from its CDN](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js) illustrates the difference. The [DevTools reference points out](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#uncompressed) that the smaller number in the requests table represents the compressed size.

[image: screenshot of Chrome DevTools showing the summary bar with the same numbers as the jQuery download listed in the table]

Comment: @p.s.w.g no problem. Edited to add references.

Comment: hi, in using mobile data, is it the transferred size or the resources size deducted to it?

Comment: @vexingCoder I don’t understand. Can you rephrase the question?